# set array of objects into object with selected id and set objects with same key to array?

Tags: javascript

i have difficulty thinking of a solution for this, so i have array of objects e.g.:

```
const objectsArr = [
  { commment: 'hello world', bookId: '1'},
  { commment: 'foo world', bookId: '2'},
  { commment: 'bar world', bookId: '1'},
  { commment: 'bazz world', bookId: '2'},
]
```

you see i have a foreign key bookId, i want it to be the key for array of comments, i want to transform it into this:

```
const objectBookIdKey = {
  1: [{ commment: 'hello world', bookId: '1'}, { commment: 'bar world', bookId: '1'}],
  2: [{ commment: 'foo world', bookId: '2'},{ commment: 'bazz world', bookId: '2'}],
}
```

the object i created above to uses property of bookId, and has array of objects with the same bookId, I'm aware of lodash, ramda for this but i wanted to do it in js for learning. i just don't know how to do this. help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce

- Loop over `objectsArr`
- use `bookId` as key
- check if it is already on object or not, if it is not assign default value and then push the value, else push the value on existing one

```js
const objectsArr = [{ commment: 'hello world', bookId: '1'},{ commment: 'foo world', bookId: '2'},{ commment: 'bar world', bookId: '1'},{ commment: 'bazz world', bookId: '2'},]

let op = objectsArr.reduce((op,inp) => {
  op[inp.bookId] = op[inp.bookId] || []
  op[inp.bookId].push(inp)
  return op
},{})

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to making group by `bookId`

```js
const objectsArr = [
    { commment: 'hello world', bookId: '1'},
    { commment: 'foo world', bookId: '2'},
    { commment: 'bar world', bookId: '1'},
    { commment: 'bazz world', bookId: '2'},
]

const result = objectsArr.reduce((old, cur) => {
    if (old[cur.bookId]) old[cur.bookId].push(cur)
    else old[cur.bookId] = [cur]
    return old
}, {})

console.log(result)
```